# How to run cordova apps on windows 8.1 phone?

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I am working on cordova app using Ionic framework & I want to test it on windows phone. I am working on windows 7 PC and my phone is lumia which runs on windows 8.1. Testing it on android was simple just get the apk on phone install it and run. But it dosen't work this way with windows. I have got Xap file using https://build.phonegap.com/. Now I want to test it on my lumia, just copy and pasting on the phone isn't working. Anybody who can help with the process. So far by R&D I came to know that to develop any thing on win 8.1 devices I am gonna need win 8.1 sdk which only works with win 8 PC. Is there any way I can run the app on my device with the existing software that I have.

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the intel xdk to build a windows 8 version and put it on your phone. Grab the intel xdk here https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk, import your html5 project, hit the build tab at the top, follow the step by step instructions, build for windows 8, install it on phone and profit. You should not need a windows 8 pc for this to work as intel builds it on their servers and you simply download the app. I run this in ubuntu and do android, iphone, and any ohter build i need.

Comment: if you have any questions let me know, hope this works for you